# JavaFX: How do you execute files located in your package?

Tags: java, file, class, methods, javafx

If I have a .png file located in my package that I want to open when a button widget is pressed. The only information I can find is about file choosers, but that isn't helpful because I already know the exact location. How do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(File file);
```

Which tries to open files with standard applications. Here is the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop()